SSRS how to hid/unhide total rows based on column values
I am needing to hide rows only if none of the column totals are <> zero:
                    2021             2022

10250-0650 ......................$0......................$ 188,804.07 show row
Total 10250-0650 ...........$0.......................$ 188,804.07 show row
10290-6370 ............$ 363,933.75......................$0 ........   show row
Total 10290-6370... $ 363,933.75.....................$0..........show row
12500-0000.......................$0................................. $0 .........hide row
Total 12500-0000............$0..................................$0          ...........hide row
I am using runningValues for row/column totals, detail lines are hidden.
I have tried everything I can think of but I can't come up with a solution.

I had to use a truth table to figure out your question :)

sorry, new to posting and saw how bad it was, hopefully it makes more sense.

I read it again. From the data, it appears that you want to hide the rows when the sum of all column sums, within the group is non-zero.

I can do that but what if 2 of the dynamic columns cancel each other out, column1 value 10 and column 2 value -10, the column totals to 0 but I don't want to hide this row because there is a value in 1 or more of the columns.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
